# How do you deploy civicrm from git?

Tags: deployment, git

For folks that maintain their own patches to civicrm-core stored via git, how do you deploy? For many years, I've been sourcing `distmaker/dists/common.sh` and running things manually (`dm_generate_vendor`, etc). I'm wondering if there's a better way.

I think I'm looking or the opposite of [gitify](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit/blob/master/bin/gitify). I've looked at [releaser](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit/blob/master/bin/releaser) which seems like the right idea, but I'm scared off by the comments ("If you're not using it to manage the official releases on civicrm.org, then... eh... good luck...").

Is there anything simple that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Civi generate tarballs of master or last/future release branch nightly. You could try downloading them from [here](https://download.civicrm.org/latest/)

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The problem is that I maintain a handful of patches in our git repo, so I want to build a tar ball specifically from our git repo.